# How can I bootstrap a self-written function with two input arguments in MATLAB 2018a?

Tags: matlab, statistics

I want to bootstrap pairwise spectral-granger-causality estimates (f), which I obtain through auto covariance sequences (G), as well as frequency resolutions (fres). The function is as follows:

```
f = autocov_to_spwcgc(G,fres)
```

where G is always 3D (2x2x500(for example)), yet varies in length of the third dimension. fres is empty, since the function calculates it itself whenever free is empty.

I tried to implement bootstrapping as follows:

```
bootstat=bootstrp(1000,@autocov_to_spwcgc,G,fres);
```

but I get the following error:

```
Index in position 1 exceeds array bounds.
```

Does anyone know how to properly implement bootstrapping here?

Comment: With a simple search I could find more than 20 definitions for _bootstrapping_. This word has a different meaning for every field it is used in. I think you should not assume that everybody understand the meaning you intend, and you should give a better explaination of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Take a look at this from the Matlab FEX: [Multidimensional bootstrapping](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/50416-multidimensional-bootstrapping)

Comment: @Hoki in Tydurs defence, he did add the tag 'statistics', but I agree that when talking about bootstrapping on SO you need to be specific.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry I thought the statistics tag would be enough. So when talking about bootstrapping here, I am referring to a statistical resampling method. Basically, through bootstrapping, I want to make my sample estimates a bit more accurate. This is achieved through calculating the intended parameter (Autocovariance in my case) repeatedly by drawing different observations out of my sample and taking the average value of all those calculations. I hope this makes it a bit more clear...  @rinkert Thanks a lot, I will check it out =)